# what's the difference of optionalDependencies and peerDependenciesMeta's optional?

Tags: javascript, npm

both of them are marking dependency as optional, so what's the use-case of each?

Is `peerDependenciesMeta` for npm package and the `optionalDependencies` for project?

I have a npm package, some modules in it need dependency `foo`, but if you don't import it, the relative peerDependency is able to not install

Comment: Take a look here https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

`peerDependenciesMeta` allows specifying `peerDependencies` as optional
`optionalDependencies` allows specifying regular `dependencies` as optional

---

Entries in `optionalDependencies` have the same semantics as entries in `dependencies`.  I.e., transitive `optionalDependencies` may end up in nested node_modules, and installed packages can have their own copies of their `optionalDependencies` available to them, at conflicting versions with each other.

`peerDependencies` are always shared (singletons) and installed in the top-level node_modules.  They must not be installed in nested node_modules if they conflict.  `peerDependenciesMeta` allows you to specify some `peerDependencies` as optional.

See the npm docs for [optionalDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies) and [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) for more info.